# Spring reactive file integration

Tags: spring-integration, reactive

I am trying to use spring-integration-file to poll a directory and create a reactive stream from files placed in this directory. This is working for the most part, but when I place a file but have no subscriber in place I get an exception. To demonstrate the problem I have written a small demo application:

```
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.Pollers;
import org.springframework.integration.file.dsl.Files;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.io.File;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Publisher<Message<File>> reactiveSource() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("."))
                                .patternFilter("*.csv"),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
                .channel("processFileChannel")
                .toReactivePublisher();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/files", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> files() {
        return Flux.from(reactiveSource())
                .map(message -> message.getPayload().getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

So if I now do a curl to localhost:8080/files and then place a csv file in the root directory of the project everything is fine, I see the path of the file as response to my curl. But when I don't do a curl and then place a file in the root directory I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The [bean 'reactiveSource.channel#0'; defined in: 'com.example.demo.DemoApplication'; 
from source: 'bean method reactiveSource'] doesn't have subscribers to accept messages
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.doSend(FluxMessageChannel.java:61)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
        ... 38 more
```

I thought one of the attributes of reactive streams was that when there was no subscriber the stream would not start due to the stream being lazy. But apparently this is not the case. Could someone explain what I would need to do to have the stream not start if there is no subscriber?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use one of the latest version, then you can use a `FluxMessageChannel` channel instead of that `DirectChannel` for the `"processFileChannel"`. This way a `SourcePollingChannel` adapter will becomes reactive and indeed the source is not going to be polled until a subscription happens to that `FluxMessageChannel`.

You then create a `Flux` in your `files()` API from this `FluxMessageChannel` - no need in the `.toReactivePublisher()`.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/reactive-streams.html#source-polling-channel-adapter

The point is that `.toReactivePublisher()` just makes an integration flow as a `Publisher` exactly at this point. Everything before this point is in regular, imperative way and works independently from the downstream logic.

**UPDATE**

Something like this:

```
@Bean
FluxMessageChannel filesChannel() {
    return new FluxMessageChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow reactiveSource() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("."))
                                .patternFilter("*.csv"),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
                .channel(filesChannel())
                .get();
    }

@GetMapping(value = "/files", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> files() {
        return Flux.from(filesChannel())
                .map(message -> ((File) message.getPayload()).getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks very much for your response. Could you please post some sample code how I should do this? I had already read the documentation quite intensively but I am unable to get things working from that. Thanks!

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thank you Artem, much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Artem, one more followup question if that's alright. I noticed that after I close the subscriber, for example by terminating the curl call, if I then place another csv file in the polled directory then again I get the same error message about there being no subscribers to accept messages. It seems like when the client closes its connection this doesn't translate to the subscription being cancelled. Can you please show how I would go about canceling the subscription upstream?

Comment: Yeah... That's the way the `FluxMessageChannel` is implemented: once subscribed - it is not cancelled until the end of application. We probably should think about some improvement over there... Feel free to raise a GH issue!

Comment: I'll work out a complete example and raise the issue. Thanks again Artem!